# (Oracle) SQL iterative self join until where condition is fulfilled

Tags: oracle, recursion, oracle12c

Lets assume I have this sample data:

```
start   end
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       4
4       3
3       2
2       1  
1       7
7       8
9       10
```

How do I build the selectstatement if I want to have the following results:

if start = 1 and end = 5:

```
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
```

if start = 1 and end = 4:

```
1       2
2       3
3       4
```

if start = 9 and end = 11:

```
no result
```

Thank you !

Comment: Tag your question with the version of Oracle you are using.

Comment: I've changed the tag :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the graph created by your data is in the form of a tree structure:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
START WITH "start" = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR "end" = "start"
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
START WITH "end" = 5
CONNECT BY PRIOR "start" = "end"
```

Comment: Starting from 1 and working down the tree may (depending on the OP's data) generate a lot of rows, in which case the INTERSECT will prove expensive. It may be better to have the top-down query select from the output of the bottom-up query (instead of using INTERSECT).

Comment: Sorry I have to change the data a little bit and need a new solution. It's not a tree structure, but instead like a network. I changed the data because the problem is that the direction can be reversed too, so from 1 to 5, there would also be from 5 to 1

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM t
  start with "end" = 5  ------------> desired end
  connect by prior "start" =  "end"
)  
where 
  "start" >= 1 ---------------------> desired start
order by "start"  
;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the table qould have dynamic values and I can't select everything using the UNION ALL :(

Comment: @Alex you don't need the `with` part, it's only to test the statement, i have remove it from my answer. replace  `t` with your table name

Answer (score 0):

Working up from the descendant to the ancestor is generally easier (faster) since there is no branching anywhere. Working down from a node to its children is more expensive, since there may be many branches to visit. So, for a fast answer it is best to start from the descendant, work up the tree, STOP the recursive query when the desired ancestor is reached, and then simply check whether the last ancestor is the desired one or not.

If you have a lot of data and performance may be important, you might want to try the different solutions and see which works best for you.

In the solution below :ancestor and :descendant are bind variables - they are assigned values in your application. If you use SQL Developer or Toad you can assign them values easily, as you try to run the query.

```
with
     prep ( s, e , lvl ) as (
            select "start", "end", level as lvl 
            from   table_name
            connect by prior "start"  = "end"
                   and prior "start" != :ancestor
            start with "end" = :descendant
     )
select s as "start", e as "end"
from   prep
where  (select max(s) keep (dense_rank last order by lvl) from prep) = :ancestor
order by lvl desc
;
```